# How do you install dependent programs with a batch file?

Tags: winapi, batch-file

I'd like to install two programs (program.exe, program_sp1.exe) via batch script.

The problem is that the first install adds environment variables that are needed by the 2nd.

Is there a good way to run the 2nd installer in a new command prompt so the values are picked up, but without user interaction to close it?

Answer (score -1):

I've tried this in a Windows 7 Machine. 
You should be able to run program.exe and the run cmd and then run your program_sp1.exe, and an exit as the cmd is running another version in itself with the updated environment variables.